# ObjectDisposedException error in Release, but not in Debug

Tags: .net, file-io, f#, runtime-error

I am writing an F# app and want to log certain information during its execution. To do so, I set the Console output to a .txt file. I do so as follows:

```
type VMwareInterface(serviceUrl:string, userName:string, password:string, baseSnapshotName:string) =  
    let vimClient = new VimClientImpl()
    let vimSession = vimClient.Login(serviceUrl, userName, password)

    // Logging
    let fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"./VMInteractorLog.txt", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
    let streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileStream)
    do System.Console.SetOut(streamWriter)

    [...]

    override x.Finalize () = 
        vimClient.Logout()
        streamWriter.Close()

    [...]
```

And I log stuff the following way:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("ERROR isolating the single VM matching name " + vmName)
```

When I run the application in debug, all is well. The file is created, written to and closed properly. Unfortunately, when I run it in release, I get the following error:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
    at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
    at System.IO.FileStream.Flush(Boolean flushToDisk)
    at System.IO.FileStream.Flush()
    at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
    at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
    at System.IO.StreamWriter.Close()
```

What could cause this?

**EDIT:**

Just wanted to add that the file is properly created in release, but it is not written to prior to getting the mentioned error.

**EDIT2:**

I have implemented the IDisposable interface as follows:

```
let mutable disposed = false

let cleanup (disposing:bool) = 
    if not disposed then
        disposed <- true

    if disposing then
        vimClient.Logout()
        streamWriter.Close()
        fileStream.Close()

interface System.IDisposable with
    member x.Dispose() =
        cleanup(true)
        System.GC.SuppressFinalize(x)

override x.Finalize () = 
    cleanup(false)
```

This has removed the error I was getting, though the file is still not written to (the file is blank after running my F# app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a good idea to reference managed objects from the finalizer as the GC may have already collected them. Finalizers are only necessary when allocating unmanaged memory like an IntPtr and you want to make sure its always released. The correct way to implement a type that creates disposables internally (like your FileStream) is to use the [dispose pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx#finalizable_types). This gives the user of the type the opportunity to release resources in a timely fashion.

In summary VMwareInterface should implement IDisposable using the pattern above. The Finalizer override is not needed.

EDIT: Corrected your indentation.

```
let cleanup (disposing:bool) = 
    if not disposed then
        disposed <- true
        if disposing then
            vimClient.Logout()
            streamWriter.Close()
            fileStream.Close()
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion which helped partly, please see my second edit to see what I have done

Comment: What do you mean partly improved? Are you getting the same error or a different one? Whats improved? I fixed your cleanup function indentation.

Comment: I am not getting the error anymore, though the Console output is not redirected to the file (the file is blank)

Comment: I had just forgot to set streamWriter.AutoFlush <- true